# Outlook add-in - Trigger JS function to execute on selecting recipient

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I would like to trigger a task pane to open when the user selects/changes the 'To' recipient for my Outlook add-in.
I have found the code for wiring up the RecipientChanged event:

```
  Office.initialize = function () {  
  $(document).ready(function () {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged, itemChanged);
  });
```

However, I want this code to be triggered on 'startup' of composing or replying to an email as opposed to having to trigger the task pane to from a ribbon button.

Feels like I am looking for the entry point to add this event wiring to.

I am using Outlook 365 latest for this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on [our user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins).

It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote [the existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19567780-allow-autorun-of-outlook-addins). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen an add-in that does this however. Its the "Hubspot" add-in. I'm wondering whether that add-in is built as a VSTO as opposed to web add-in. Not sure whether this feature is available in VSTO/COM add-ins?

Comment: Ok, Currently Web add-in does not have this capability.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with event based activation of your outlook adding

Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch)

Comment: @user8174007 did you tried with OnNewMessageCompose event?